# Editing mosaic plot labels and axes values as shown on the example

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I am a beginner in R and I need to reconstruct my mosaic plot from the data below.

[image]

The plot isn't quite what I imagined, the labeling is all wrong and I don't want to display the contingency table. I tried different lines to change the label but it kept giving me more distorted plots. I would like to edit it to look like the plot on example.

[image]

I want to put the disasters as the x-axis and the countries (under ISO column) on the y-axis. I would also like to describe the numbers on each box. How to correct this script or write a better one with ggplot2 or vcd or MASS packages?

**Data**

```
ISO Flood   Storm   Cyclone Heavy rain  Drought Landslides
AGO 5000    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
BDI 500 500 NA  800 NA  3600
BEN 260 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
BFA 6248    NA  NA  NA  2500    NA
BWA 833 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
CAF 5000    4000    NA  644 NA  NA
CIV 987 NA  NA  NA  NA  4000
CMR 655 NA  NA  NA  NA  520
COD 300 50  400 254 NA  40
```

**Code**

```
getwd()
"G:/"
trial_one <- read.csv("trial_one.csv", TRUE, sep = ",",
     na.strings = TRUE)
mosaicplot( trial_one, main = "Enviromental changes by Country",
      sub = "SSA",
      xlab = "Mosaic plot",
     ylab = "Extreme_changes",
     las = 1,
     color = "skyblue2",
     border = "chocolate")
#mosaicplot(events)
```

`structure(list(ï..ISO = structure(1:9, .Label = c("AGO", "BDI",  "BEN", "BFA", "BWA", "CAF", "CIV", "CMR", "COD"), class = "factor"),  Flood = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("5,000",  "833", "260", "655", "500", "987", "300",  "5,000", "6,248"), class = "factor"), Storm = structure(c(4L,  2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("4,000", "500",  "50", "NA"), class = "factor"), Cyclone = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("400", "NA" ), class = "factor"), Heavy.rain = structure(c(4L, 3L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("644", "254",  "800", "NA"), class = "factor"), Drought = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2,500", "NA" ), class = "factor"), Landslides = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("4,000", "520", "40",  "3600", "NA"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -9L))`

Comment: Would it be possible to post your data object 'trial_one' in the body of your question? This can be done by running `dput(trial_one)` in the console, and then copy and pasting the output into your edited post. By doing so it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: thank you very much @ Jamex Z for the edit.

Comment: Based on the code you have shown, after you read in the csv file data into R with the line ```trial_one <- read.csv("trial_one.csv", TRUE, sep = ",",
     na.strings = TRUE)```, you should have an "object" in the "global environment" that has the name "trial_one". Once you have this object, type `dput(trial_one)` into the console and hit return. This should cause the console to display your data in a format that can easily be copy-and-pasted. You can then paste it into your question by using the 'Edit' link below your question.

Comment: I just posted the output, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Now it will be easier for people to use the data to work with you question.